# Jquery, add buttons under elements, and remember which element the button belongs to

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check out my code here

http://jsfiddle.net/bYDPr/20/

So I have some HTML textarea elements

```
<textarea id="area11ba" class="showEditor">1</textarea><br/>
<textarea id="area22ab" class="showEditor">2</textarea><br/>
<textarea id="area33cd" class="showEditor">3</textarea><br/>
<textarea id="area4fg">4</textarea><br/>
<textarea id="area55ed" class="showEditor">5</textarea><br/>
```

And I wanna add an "Editor" button under each textarea that has "showEditor" class, then when people click on the Editor button, it should alert the content of that textarea.

Here is my attempt

```
$("textarea[class*='showEditor']").each(function(index) {

    textareaid = $(this).attr('id');
    buttonId = "editorButton" + index;
    editorButton = '<div class="editorButton"><a id="' + buttonId + '">Editor</a></div>';
    $(editorButton).insertAfter(this);

    that = this;

    $('#' + buttonId).click(function() {
        content = $('#'+ textareaid ).val();
        alert(content);
    });


});
```

But unfortunately the alerted value is always 5, which is the last defined element.

How can this be done properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you mean to skip "showEditor" class for area 4, but if not, here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/bYDPr/8/

Basically, change

`content = $(that).val();`

to

`content = $('#area' + (index+1)).val();`

EDIT: Change "that = this;" to "var that = this;"

```
$("textarea[class*='showEditor']").each(function(index) {

        buttonId = "editorButton" + index;
        editorButton = '<div class="editorButton"><a id="' + buttonId + '">Editor</a></div>';
        $(editorButton).insertAfter(this);

        var that = this;

        $('#' + buttonId).click(function() {
            content = $(that).val();
            alert(content);
        });     
});
```

Comment: Thank you MK_Dev, this is close to what I need, but not exactly, I think my example was not illustrative enough, those textarea IDs are not necessarily in numerical order, and area 4 was meant to be skipped, because I don't wanna show this for all textareas, anyways I changed the code slightly to be closer to what I want http://jsfiddle.net/bYDPr/20/

Comment: In that case it's even easier. Make sure "that" has "var" next to it, otherwise it doesn't capture the value of "that" properly and uses the last value assigned to it: http://jsfiddle.net/YyuuF/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('.editorButton').live('click', some_function);
});

function some_function(){
    content = $(this).prev().val();
    alert(content);
}


$('.showEditor').each(function(index){
    buttonId = "editorButton" + index;
    editorButton = '<div class="editorButton"><a id="' + buttonId + '">Editor</a></div>';
    $(this).insertAfter(editorButton);
});
```

**Edited**: in response to your changes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the scope of the evaluation of 'this'.

Try this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/richfreedman/bfVnm/1/

```
$("textarea[class*='showEditor']").each(function(index) {

    buttonId = "editorButton" + index;
    editorButton = '<div class="editorButton"><a id="' + buttonId + '">Editor</a></div>';
    $(editorButton).data("editor", this).insertAfter(this).click(function(event) {
        textarea = $(this).data("editor")
        alert($(textarea).val())
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi GreyBeardedGeek, this seems like a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the var before declaring the variables !